# Can I replace a Titanium iPhone app with an XCode app in App Store?

Tags: xcode, titanium, provisioning

I have an existing Titanium created iPhone app in the App Store called Impact Summit. I would like to rewrite this using XCode instead now that I have learned enough Objective-C to probably pull it off. I am also doing this on a different laptop than was used to create the original Titanium versions.

1. Do you think I be able to push an updated .ipa version made with XCode only and replace the current Titanium version and have users receive an update without any issues?
2. Is there something I need to do to make sure the Provisioning Profile or other licensing stuff transfers ok to the new laptop and into XCode?

Trying to avoid telling users to uninstall old one and download new one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your whole application. All you need to do is keep app id and provisioning profiles the same.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rewrite it completely but you can just use the apple id and provisioning profile used to create it originally to push an update, users will be able to download the update instead of redownloading an app